# In Visual Studio Code using Python, Is there a way to see the contents of a module without first having to type a letter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I'm in Visual Studio Code using Python. When importing a module I would like to see the classes it contains so as to make sure it has what I'm looking for. Is there a way to see the contents of a module without first having to type a letter? In IDLE sometims it is possible to do this.

For example, in VSC, at the start of a script:

```
from random import #At this point a list should somehow appear
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you typed `"from random import "` hit `Ctrl+Space` to bring up autocomplete menu, it is a default shortcut but if you wish to change it you can, just search for `Trigger Suggest` in Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly. Couldn't find that anywhere. "Trigger suggestions" was a key word here. I found the full shortcuts list also: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf